# Guice named binding to selectively provide an instance

Tags: java, binding, guice

I am trying to provide a dummy client/config based on some conditions and I can think of  implementing as shown below. I added 'if' statement in the provider to provide a different implementation of `FooClient` and `FooConfig`. `DummyFooClient` and `DummyFooConfig` both implement the same interface.
I wasn't sure if adding the conditional logic in the provider logic is a good design pattern. If it's not, could you suggest a better approach?

```
class FooClientModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("fooClient")
    @Singleton
    public FooClient provideFooClient(@Named("fooConfig") final Config config) {
        String var = config.getVar();
        if (var == "test") {
            return new DummyFooClient();
        }
        return new FooClient(config)
    }
    
    @Provides
    @Named("fooGateway")
    @Singleton
    public FooGateway provideFooGateway(@Named("fooClient") final FooClient fooClient) {
        return new FooGateway(mvpAtatClient);
    }
}

class FooConfigModule {
    @Provides
    @Named("fooConfig")
    @Singleton
    public FooConfig provideFooConfig() {
        if (configNotRequired) {
            return new DummyFooConfig();
        }
        return new FooConfig()
    }

}
```